# Is there a way to edit my html file from chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know if there is a way for chrome to directly edit my html files while editing it in dev tool's "element tab". What I mean by directly editing is while I am editing my html file in the devtool it will also edit the file in my local and save it.

[image]

Comment: [Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow) is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, No you can't.

Right click, choose **edit as html** to edit the live preview.
but it edit the loaded instance only. The original file cannot be edited

Comment: Sorry , my question wasn't clear. I am actually asking if there is a way to directly edit my html file (file in the local) directly using the dev tools.

Comment: Edited. The answer is you can't

Comment: are there any alternatives to what I am looking for ?

Comment: You want edit file with live preview??

Comment: yes editing and saving.

Comment: Then, adobe Dreamweaver in _split view_ is a good tools. You can either purchase or use a keygen to generate fake keys. also lots of tools are there with live editing. A google search with _html editor with live preview_ will get you a list of tools.

Comment: Downvoter , any comments??